# Modifying sort key in awakeFromFetch doesn't update sort order

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, core-data

I have a Core Data object that has a property "completed" and also a time to reset this value:

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL completed;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * next_reset;
```

I fetch these objects with a NSFetchedResultsController, sorting on the "completed" key:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"completed" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor1,nil];
```

The wrinkle: I reset "completed" on fetch:

```
- (void)awakeFromFetch
{
    [super awakeFromFetch];

    if (!self.auto_reset || !self.completed)
    {
        return;
    }

    NSDate *now = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];
    if ([now compare:self.next_reset] == NSOrderedDescending)
    {
        self.last_reset = now;
        self.completed = NO;
    }
}
```

My problem is that this modification is not reflected in the sorting of the fetched results - I get completed items mixed in with uncompleted ones. When I complete an item "live" the sorting does update as I expect.

According to the docs, in awakeFromFetch, Core Data is not monitoring changes made to the object. I do see that even a [self.managedObjectContext save:nil]; does not save my changes made here. I've tried calling -willChangeValueForKey/-didChangeValueForKey before I modify "completed" but this doesn't change things.

Where can I do these kinds of updates to the object so that Core Data properly sees them? Obviously I don't want to do it anywhere but the model (certainly not in my controller that is fetching these objects!) but I don't see any other places to put this update code.

I at least can get this to sort of work with this code:

```
    NSDate *now = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];
    NSTimeInterval interval_to_next_reset = [self.next_reset timeIntervalSinceDate:now];
    if (interval_to_next_reset < 0.01)
    {
        interval_to_next_reset = 0.01;
    }

    [self performSelector:@selector(resetCompleted) withObject:nil afterDelay:interval_to_next_reset];
}

- (void)resetCompleted
{
    self.last_reset = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];
    self.completed = NO;
}
```

but this causes the table view to visibly rearrange itself immediately after being displayed, which isn't ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this problem by not doing it this way.

Instead of writing this code in `-awakeFromFetch` (which clearly isn't meant to be used this way) I added code in my app delegate's `-didBecomeActive` (& friends) to call a class method `+processQuestsNeedingReset` which updates all of these at once. That update *is* reflected in the table view.

Comment: This is an old question, but I've run into this same issue with an Objective-C application running on iOS 10.x.  The fetch results are returned before awakeFromFetch is called.  I also worked around this by using a non-synthesized property for my logic flow.  Has anyone else seen this before?  Is this related to a new iOS version?  Is there a fix?  Thanks!